# Facebook Getting a Users Groups (Having Problems)

Tags: facebook, token

Ive searched high and low for an answer to this on here but havent been able to find anything.  Please answer if you can, its appreciated.

**The Setup:**

Im learning how to work with the PHP Facebook API SDK by using one of the examples as a base. Im new to working with APIs so Im a little confused and have been having a problem trying to list a users groups.

**The Question:**

Ive got the app made. Ive got the proper permissions and extended permissions. I am able to get the users name and basic info.

I think my problem comes with the access token required to access the extended permission needed to get a users groups. Im not sure if Im sending it to the API correctly.

*This is what Ive got:*

```
<?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $user_groups = $facebook->api('/me/groups','GET', array( 'access_token=' => $access_token ));

        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo "Groups: " . $user_groups['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $args['scope'] = 'user_groups,user_likes';
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $args['scope'] = 'user_likes,user_groups';
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the "user_groups" permission? What's not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I dont get any results. The line is just blank. Im pretty sure I have the groups permission. The app is registering permissions for user_groups.

Comment: when i do: var_dump($user_groups); i can see that Ive got the contents of the user_groups array. But when I try and do $user_groups['name'] or anything, I get blank results.

Comment: There's no "name" in that result. Check the answer I posted for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but here are a few points:

1. There's no reasons to manually add the access token when using a facebook sdk, those will add the access token for you. Should be:

   $user_groups = $facebook->api('/me/groups','GET');
2. The format of the json encoded result for the *"/me/groups"* is completely different than of the *"/me"*.
   Where the result for "/me" is just a set of key/value data, the result for "/me/groups" is wrapped inside a "data" parameter which is an array of objects.
   As it states in the [User Object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) (under the *groups* connection):

   > An array of objects containing the version(old-0 or new Group-1),
   >   name, id, administrator (if user is the administrator of the Group)
   >   and bookmark_order(at what place in the list of group bookmarks on the
   >   homepage, the group shows up for the user).
3. When in doubt about how facebook responses to different queries, use the [Graph Explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with which you can test the different queries and see the responses that facebook returns.
   For example the [result for /me](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me) and the [result for /me/groups](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/groups)